# Simple Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to write my first Angular directive to add pagination functionality to my app. 
I'm keeping it simple for now and want to have the directive just share the scope of the controller.

In my controller, I have a scoped var called:

```
$scope.pages
```

Inside my directive's linking function, I can do:

```
console.dir($scope)
```

to see the contents of the controller's scope object, but if I try to access the pages property, it comes back as undefined.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
myDirectives.directive("mdPagination", function(){
    return {
        template: '',
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1000,
        scope: false,
        link: function($scope, el, attrs){
            console.dir($scope.pages);  //returns undefined
            el.text('hello world');
        },
    }
});
```

Edit: I'm aware there's pagination modules out there, but my needs are modest and I thought building my own would be an easy way to start learning how to build directives.

Comment: try removing `scope: false`

Comment: How is $scope.pages populated in your controller? Through an AJAX request?

Comment: Check out these existing AngularJS pagination modules @ http://ngmodules.org/modules?query=pagination

Comment: Can we see your controller that sets `$scope.pages` and the HTML where the controller and your directive are used?

Comment: when is the $scope.pages is populated in the controller ? If it is populated in the controller directly it works for me.  

p.s. in the link function you dont need to name it $scope, the scope will be anything you pass as the first argument, name does not matter in the link function as it does in the controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is directives linking functions are run before controllers are, so you typically can't access scope values during this linking phase. There are a couple other ways to do this. The most immediate way to solve your problem is with `$scope.$watch`. So something like this should work:

```
$scope.watch('pages', function(pages) {
  console.dir(pages);
});
```

This works just fine for lost of circumstances. I would also suggest decoupling your controller from the scope it is declared in a bit by using an attribute to pass in an expression (property name basically) for your watch. A simple example might look like this:

```
<div my-directive="myProperty">

link: function($scope, el, attrs) {
  $scope.watch(attrs.myDirective, function(value) {
   //do something you need to do with the value here
  });
}
```

However as you add complexity to your directive you may want to give your directive it's own controller to manage state without directly calling watches. This controller can either use a child scope belonging to the directive itself with `scope: true` or just use the parent scope with `scope: false`. Your choice will likely depend upon need. Then you could have:

```
myDirectives.directive("mdPagination", function(){
    return {
        template: '',
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1000,
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
             console.dir($scope.pages);

        }],
        link: function($scope, el, attrs){
          $element.text('hello world');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

By default, the directive shares its scope with the controller. To do that, you must not having a "scope" attribute in your object, like that:

```
myDirectives.directive("mdPagination", function(){
    return {
        template: '',
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1000,
        link: function($scope, el, attrs){
            console.dir($scope.pages);
            el.text('hello world');
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: The scope attribute doesn't have anything to do with the problem. You can't directly access $scope values in the linking function reliably. You have to attach a watch to it.

Answer (score -1):

@Sandro is right.  You set the `scope` property in your directive to `false` which means that the scope will not inherit (or share) its properties with the controller.  If you remove the false, it should work as you intend it.

The docs for how to use `$scope` are here: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

The developer guide for creating directives has a lot of good info about how to setup your directive so that it gives you the scope you want.  Those docs are here: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/guide/directive

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, if you set scope to 'true' it creates a separate scope for the directive. http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/guide/directive

Comment: Actually it creates a child scope for the directive which inherits, if you set it to false it *uses* the current scope it is declared in directly. In fairness this is a fairly confusing aspect of directive design.